# What is a good way to store order in an SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I develop and maintain a Google Tasks app on Android. Currently I have a class that contains lists and tasks, in order, in an `ArrayList`. I'm thinking of switching to SQLite to better structure the app. I'm not sure what the best and easiest way to store the order of tasks in the database would be though.

Right now, I can simply `remove` and `add` items at different indices and obviously the other List rows indices are in correct order. With an SQLite database, I can store a positional number in each row, and everytime I move a task, update the following rows accordingly.

The problem with that system is concurrency and maintainability: If a row's position is updated (and the following rows' positions are incremented/decremented) at the same time a tasks sync is happening it could get messy, as the sync is changing row positions too.

I could add a Mutex lock, but I don't want to do that, I want users to be able to update data at the same time as a sync, and if a conflict occurs, one of the new positions be discarded, without the following rows being messed up.

My question: What is the best way to store and update order within an SQLite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with adding a `sort_position` value to each row is that it can't be updated atomically, because to swap two items in the list you need to change both of their positions. The database is much better at guaranteeing atomicity when the changes are to the same row.

A better way would be to treat the ordering column as a priority - the values can be sparse so a rows can be placed between two adjacent ones, and two items can have the same value without it being a consistency problem. If the values are sparse, you can swap two items by just changing one value, so concurrent updates are more gracefully handled (although you might still get unexpected situations if two agents are trying to rearrange the same part of the list).

An alternative way of handling it might be to have the ordering be stored as one value in a different table - for example as a list of item ids. This has the advantage of allowing more precise control of the ordering while not ever getting  garbled state from interleaved updates, but is more complicated (handling missing or unknown items, how to handle both updating at the same time). I wouldn't try this unless you really need it.

Comment: I'm not sure how treating them as a priority would make it so you would only have to change one value. For example, if A is priority 1, B is priority 2, and I want to put C in between A and B, I have to shift B to 3 and C to 2.

Comment: That's what I meant by being able to have the priority values be sparse - have them be non-consecutive. You can't do it if all of the values are consecutive, but if they're separated by say, 100, then you can easily set it to be a value between the priority of the items it needs to appear after and before.

Comment: That's how Google Tasks API does it, but you would run out of room wouldn't you? For example, if your list looked like: 0, 1, 3, 6, 12, 25, 50, 100 (last task.) You couldn't add a task at the beginning, as the position would be 0/2 which would also be 0.

Comment: Well, there's nothing stopping you from using floats for priority (although you'd still *eventually* run out of room).

Answer (score 1):

"Best way" I don't know.

But, as in another RDBMS, adding a column for such is a good solution.

Handling that column will imply some code, but in SQLite, you can implement this logic in database, using triggers.

Here goes a sample, using a back table and a view which performs magic:

```
-- Main table, where data belongs
CREATE TABLE _t(n, o);
-- Table view, which will handle all inserts, updates and deletes
CREATE VIEW t AS SELECT * FROM _t;

-- Triggers:
-- Raise error when inserting invalid index (out of bounds or non integer)
CREATE TRIGGER t_ins_err INSTEAD OF INSERT ON t
WHEN NEW.o<1 OR NEW.o>(SELECT COUNT()+1 FROM _t) OR CAST(NEW.o AS INT) <> NEW.o
BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Invalid index!'); END;
-- Increments all indexes when new row inserted in middle of table
CREATE TRIGGER t_ins INSTEAD OF INSERT ON t
WHEN NEW.o BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT COUNT() FROM _t)+1
BEGIN
    UPDATE _t SET o=o+1 WHERE o>=NEW.o;
    INSERT INTO _t VALUES(NEW.n, NEW.o);
END;
-- Insert row in last when supplied index is NULL
CREATE TRIGGER t_ins_last INSTEAD OF INSERT ON t
WHEN NEW.o IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _t VALUES(NEW.n, (SELECT COUNT()+1 FROM _t));
END;
-- Decrements indexes when item is removed
CREATE TRIGGER t_del INSTEAD OF DELETE ON t
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM _t WHERE o=OLD.o;
    UPDATE _t SET o=o-1 WHERE o>OLD.o;
END;
-- Raise error when updating to invalid index
CREATE TRIGGER t_upd_err INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF o ON t
WHEN NEW.o NOT BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT COUNT() FROM _t) OR CAST(NEW.o AS INT)<>NEW.o OR NEW.o IS NULL;
BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Invalid index!'); END;
-- Decrements indexes when item is moved up
CREATE TRIGGER t_upd_up INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF o ON t
WHEN NEW.o BETWEEN OLD.o+1 AND (SELECT COUNT() FROM t)
BEGIN
    UPDATE _t SET o=NULL WHERE o=OLD.o;
    UPDATE _t SET o=o-1 WHERE o BETWEEN OLD.o AND NEW.o;
    UPDATE _t SET o=NEW.o WHERE o IS NULL;
END;
-- Increments indexes when item is moved down
CREATE TRIGGER t_upd_down INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF o ON t
WHEN NEW.o BETWEEN 1 AND OLD.o-1
BEGIN
    UPDATE _t SET o=NULL WHERE o=OLD.o;
    UPDATE _t SET o=o+1  WHERE o BETWEEN NEW.o AND OLD.o;
    UPDATE _t SET o=NEW.o WHERE o IS NULL;
END;

-- Tests:
INSERT INTO t(n) VALUES('a1');
INSERT INTO t(n) VALUES('b1');
INSERT INTO t(n) VALUES('c1');
INSERT INTO t(n) VALUES('d1');
INSERT INTO t VALUES('e1', 5);
INSERT INTO t VALUES('z1', 20);
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY o;
INSERT INTO t VALUES('b2', 2);
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY o;
DELETE FROM t WHERE n='b1';
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY o;
UPDATE t SET o=4 WHERE o=2;
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY o;
UPDATE t SET o=3 WHERE o=5;
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY o;
```

Comment: How atomic is this method?

Comment: IFAIK, this is atomic has any operation handled by trigger or completes successfully or completely rolls back.